# How to sort a list of tuples by the alphabetical ordering of one of its elements

Tags: python

I have a list of tuples, say (name, number, birthday, gender).  If I wanted to reverse sort this list by their birthday, how could I sort this in python?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This returns a new object:

```
>>> import operator
>>> sorted(my_list, key=operator.itemgetter(2), reverse=True)
```

Or, in-place:

```
>>> import operator
>>> mylist.sort(key=operator.itemgetter(2), reverse=True)
```

If you want to sort by two values; assuming tuples are like (name, birthday, time);

```
>>> mylist.sort(key=operator.itemgetter(1, 2), reverse=True)
```

Comment: Thanks!  And what if there was also a "time" attribute, and you wanted to sort first by date, and then by time?

Comment: You could use a function returns a tuple as key.

Comment: I think you misunderstood.  I mean if I want to sort by birthday and birthtime.  So somebody born at 1:23 on Jun 22 is first, then somebody born at 20:22 on Jun 22.  Then somebody born at 5:30 on Jun 23 (sorted by date, but tied dates are sorted by time)  <-- this was before you edited your comment

Comment: Thanks for the update.  Your final line has no call to itemgetter, why is that?

Comment: Because I thought when returning a tuple, lambda is easier, but I learned now, itemgetter could take more than one parameter and return a tuple too, so changing answer again :). `itemgetter(1)` is `lambda i: i[1]` and `itemgetter(1,2)` is `lambda i: i[1], i[2]`